# React : Render returns createElement

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I just started to learn React and I'm using it with a Rails backend.

In my view I have :

```
<%= react_component 'Products', { data: @products } %>
```

It works fine with this static code :

```
var Products = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {products: this.props.data};
  },

  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {products: []};
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="products">

        <h2 className="title">List of products</h2>

        <table className="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Company</th>
              <th>RRP</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>AAA</td>
              <td>BBB</td>
              <td>CCC</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

I've got my table displayed well.
The next step is to have the same result but with each line representing  a new product's element. So I start to create a new React Class in the same file :

```
var ProductLine = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>CCC</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
});
```

My problem is, how can I render this `ProductLine` in my table ? Because if I do this :

```
<tbody>
  React.createElement ProductLine
</tbody>
```

The line is considered as plain text and not rendered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found the solution just after posting this question.

[This post called Thinking in React](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) from Pete Hunt is very useful, especially for a React newbie. Also, the example is almost the same as my situation...

```
var ProductRow = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{this.props.product.name}</td>
        <td>{this.props.product.company_id}</td>
        <td>{this.props.product.price}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
});


var ProductTable = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var rows = [];

    this.props.data.forEach(function(product) {
      rows.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.id} />);
    });

    return (
      <div className="products">

        <h2 className="title">List of products</h2>

        <table className="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Company</th>
              <th>RRP</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {rows}
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but `<ProductLine` /> is how you would instantiate a component within the render function of another parent component i.e.:

```
<tbody>
  <ProductLine />
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tahir but I found another solution from the React website ;)

Comment: doh! and I was thinking you wanted to push only one item into it. Of course a loop would help. Glad you resolved it :)

Comment: Yup that's right I wanted to because I wanted to go slowly step by step but... :)

Comment: **[An example](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/69z2wepo/11999/)** I just made. Thought I should share.